# If the J-2X is too powerful for SLS, why was it appropriate for Saturn V?

Tags: engines, saturn-v, sls, j-2

Reading an article [about new engines for the SLS](http://aviationweek.com/space/final-sls-engines-are-still-unknown) (Summary: There is no plan what to do once the current SSME's are expended), they mention that the J-2X is too powerful for the upper stage of SLS.

> Ultimately‭, ‬the 294,000-lb‭.-‬thrust J-2X engine may be too powerful for the SLS upper stage‭, ‬at least in the 105,000-ton Block IB‭ ‬intermediate variant en route to the 130-ton version needed for Mars missions‭. ‬“Essentially‭, ‬that stage wants to be about‭ [‬120,000‭ ‬lb‭. ‬thrust‭] ‬total‭,‬”‭ ‬May says‭, ‬and the agency is considering four RL-10s or two‭ ‬“60k-class”‭ ‬engines instead‭.

The original J-2 was about 234 Klbs of thrust. The J-2X seems to be uprated to 294 Klbs thrust.

Regardless, the J-2 was the second stage engine on Saturn V. There was a cluster of 5 J-2's. The third stage used a single J-2.

So this leaves me wondering, if the upper stage on Saturn V was appropriate at 234 Klbs thrust, why is SLS, which is meant vaguely to be in the same class, more likely to need only 120 Klbs thrust?

Comment: In both the Saturn V and SLS case, the upper stage is used both for circularization and for trans-destination injection. If SLS's booster and core leaves the upper stage in a faster trajectory than the first two Saturn V stages, less thrust (= acceleration) would be needed for the circularization burn (which is time sensitive), so that's my best hypothesis. The injection burn is fairly insensitive to thrust, and the RL-10 has better Isp than the J-2.

Comment: I'm too lazy to do a more detailed analysis but a quick glance at thrust x burn time suggests that SLS's booster/core stages pack more punch than the first two Saturn V stages.

Comment: I agree with the first 2 comments and just want to add that the SLS core likely is able to achieve a higher core burnout velocity because the RS-25 hydrolox engines have much better Isp than the F-1s.